# Viloating non-null constraint when creating new user in custom form

Tags: python, django

Im trying to create a custom registration form via AbstractUser but somehow it does not create entry in database (register new user basically)

my models.py

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, default='youremail@email.com', null=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

my forms.py

```
from index.models import UserProfile, User
from django import forms
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    middle_name = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['email', 'name', 'second_name', 'password1', 'password2', 'country', 'city', 'birthday']
        widgets = {
            'birthday': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1900, datetime.now().year + 1))
        }
```

when I try to test and register user i get this error

```
    null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (13, 1900-01-01, Switzerland, Montreux, 2018-08-23 12:07:07.367219+00, null, email@email.ch, , Alex, test, None, null, somepasswordhash...).
```

Answer (score 0):

You column `user_id` ends up being null, I don't see it in your `UserProfile` class and you table does not allow it to be null.

You either have to set its value or make it auto-increment in your table ( which seems to be what you are looking for )

Hope that can help ~~